# Meaning of "not conclude at yours"

Tags: meaning, aurora-leigh, elizabeth-barrett-browning

From Aurora Leigh:

> Have you learnt 
>   No more of women, 'spite of privilege,
>   Than still to take account too seriously
>   Of such weak flutterings? Why, we like it, sir,–
>   We get our powers and our effects that way.
>   The trees stand stiff and still at time of frost,
>   If no wind tears them; but, let summer come,
>   When trees are happy,–and a breath avails
>   To set them trembling through a million leaves
>   In luxury of emotion. Something less
>   It takes to move a woman: let her start
>   And shake at pleasure,**–nor conclude at yours**,
>   The winter's bitter,–but the summer's green.'

What is the meaning of **nor conclude at yours**?

Let a woman to start (= jerk in surprise) and shake at pleasure (as she pleases). But what is the meaning of "nor conclude at yours"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the phrase  "let her start
And shake at pleasure,–nor conclude at yours," should be understood   something like "let her start and shake at [her] pleasure, and not conclude at your [pleasure]", or, more loosely, "let her start and stop when she wants, not when you want".

There is, however, the ambiguity of "start".  Does it mean *jolt* or does it mean *begin*, as my paraphrases here take it? (My OED lists both, with the *jolt* sense coming before the *begin* sense.) The occurrence in "start and shake" makes the *jolt* sense seem more likely, but the opposition with "conclude" makes the *begin* sense more likely.  Is it allowed for a poet to use a word in two senses at once?

Comment: `Is it allowed for a poet to use a word in two senses at once?` - poets can do anything they want ;).